# How exactly works this Angular 2 example showing how to use a subcomponent property by a parent component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, javascript-framework

I am a total beginner in Angular 2 and I have the following doubt about a tutorial example that show how to access to a subcomponent property by a parent component.

Into the main component (the **app-component**) I have this **app.component.html** view:

```
<div class="container">
      <app-server-element
        *ngFor="let serverElement of serverElements"
        [srvElement]="serverElement">
      </app-server-element>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It is iterating on the **serverElements** array defined into the **app.component.ts** class, something like this:

```
serverElements = [{type: 'server', name: 'TestServer', content: 'Just a Test'}];
```

and it is using the elements (at this time only 1, but this is not important) into the `<app-server-element>` component that is a subcomponent of the `<app-component>`.

Into the **ServerElementComponent** class I have:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-server-element',
  templateUrl: './server-element.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./server-element.component.css']
})
export class ServerElementComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input('srvElement') element: {type: string, name: string, content: string};

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

So, into the **app.component.html** view I have:

```
  <app-server-element
    *ngFor="let serverElement of serverElements"
    [srvElement]="serverElement">
  </app-server-element>
```

So from what I have understood the **[srvElement]="serverElement"** means that I am accessing to this property of the **ServerElementComponent** subcomponent class (that is annotated with **@Input**

```
@Input('srvElement') element: {type: string, name: string, content: string};
```

So basically what it exactly means the previous iteration?

I am interpreting it in this way:

Iterate on the **serverElements** array (that is a generic array of Object having a specified field set that corresponds to the fields set of the **@Input('srvElement') element** defined in the **app-server-element** sub component). Then use the current **serverElement** element to build a **@Input('srvElement') element** in the used  component (used into the main view).

But I am not sure of this. What is the exact meaning of this **[srvElement]="serverElement"** syntax?

Maybe I am wrong but it seems to me something like a cast: I have a generic object that is casted to the type needed by the subcomponent. I can do it because the type defined in the subcomponent is annoted by the **@Input()** decorator and so it is accessible by the parent component.

Is it a correct interpretation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a profesional so I will try to explain it to you simply with my own words :

You start with your HTML (your first template). In it, you can see

```
<app-server-element
    *ngFor="let serverElement of serverElements"
    [srvElement]="serverElement">
</app-server-element>
```

There are several things here :

- First, you can see the selector `app-server-element`. It means that the whole tag will be replaced by an HTML template that you define in your component.
- Then you have a `*ngFor`. This is a built-in directive that allows you to repeat a tag based on a variable.
- Finally, you have the `[srvElement]` attribute. This is an **Input** attribute : what is on the right side of the equal (here `serverElement`) will be sent to your component.

In your component now, you can see

```
@Input('srvElement') element: {type: string, name: string, content: string};
```

What is done here is that you grab a reference to the input you sent previously : by doing this, it tells Angular to bind this variable to the content sent by it's "parent" component. You also give the stucture the element should have (corresponding to the structure of the variable you send in the "parent").

So to make it in a sentence, for the first element it gives :

```
Iterate through serverElements, and for each item of this list, send this item to the "child" component and replace the app-server-element tag with the HTML template of the "child" component.
```

For the second element, it gives :

```
Grab the value the "parent" component sent you, and register it in a variable so that you can use it in my HTML template (server-element.component.html)
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you have a main component "app-component" that contains a list of `serverElements`.

The template of the main component contains this loop:

```
<app-server-element
    *ngFor="let serverElement of serverElements"
    [srvElement]="serverElement">
</app-server-element>
```

It means that Angular will generate a `app-server-element` component for each item in `serverElements`.

`[srvElement]="serverElement"` means that for each `app-server-element` component, the main component (app-component) gives it the current `serverElement` as an `input`.

So if you have 2 items in `serverElements`, it will generate 2 `app-server-element` components:

- The first component will receive the first item in `serverElements`
- The second component will receive the second item in `serverElements`

You will have 2 different instances of the `app-server-element` component.

The `@Input()` decorator does not mean `accessible by the parent` but `it's a data the component can receive as input given by his parent`.